# issue with the background-color when use float:left

Tags: css

CSS:

```
ul#navlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
}

ul#navlist li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#navlist li a {
    float: left;
    width: 5em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul#navlist li a:hover {
    background-color: #369;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="navlist">
  <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Question:

If i remove this line: `float:left` inside `ul#navlist`, `background-color: #036;` will not show up, why?

Comment: On http://jsfiddle.net/ your code seems to work!

Comment: @Alesanco because there is "a workaround" by declaring the same color on the `a` elements. See the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/DZSh4/

Comment: You're right... I'm sorry I didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating an item removes it from the normal document flow. That's why you have to establish a block content on the parent element or explicitely clear the floats:

```
/* All of the following will work: */

ul#navlist {
    float: left;
   /* problem: the element itself is removed from the document flow */
}

ul#navlist {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* problem: dropdown lists will get truncated */
}

ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    /* problem: compatibility with older browsers */
}
```

Possible other solutions are to not float the `li`/`a` but use `display:inline-block` instead, which imposes a new problem of whitespace between the elements appearing as "magic margin".

All of these methods work with certain restrictions, you should choose the one, which suits you most.

Answer (score 1):

Used to this  and **remove** `float left;`

```
    ul#navlist:after{
        content:'';
        overflow:hidden;
        clear:both;
        display:table;

    }
ul#navlist li {
    display: inline-block;  // add this line
    vertical-align:top;  // add this line
}

ul#navlist li a {
    display:block; // add this line and remove float left
    width: 5em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWYLV/1/)**

Comment: Can you give a version without left margin on the anchor elements? ;)